# showing that if a function is a bijection, then there exists a an identity function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Let f:x-y be a bijection, show that foi =iof =f where i is identity function.

I know that a bijection is one which is bith noe to one and onto. The problems is that the question is so trivial that I find it difficult to prove.

Comment: If $i_y$ is the identity function on $y$ and $i_x$ is the identity function on $x$  then $i_y\circ f=f\circ i_x=f$ is true for every function $f:x\rightarrow y$. It needs not to be bijective for that. If $x\ne y$ then you are dealing with two distinct identity functions.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Recall that $(g\circ f)(x)=g(f(x))$, and that $i(x)=x$.

Comment: yeah that I know, so do I just give this hint and conclude that the fuction is identity function?

Comment: Do you know when two functions are equal?